# Incorrect assumptions for centre of mass of a cone

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integration

To find the centre of mass of a cone, I assumed that it would lie on the z-axis due to symmetry. I then also decided that if I reduced the problem to finding the z-component of the centre of mass of a right triangle lying along the z-axis I could rotate this about the z-axis and obtain a ring of centres of mass all with the same z-coordinate and different y and x co-ordinates. However, these would x and y co-ordinates would all sum to zero once again due to symmetry leaving me with the answer of COM = 2/3*h along the z axis, the same as the x component of the COM of a right triangle.

This is obviously wrong but I can't figure out the flaw in my logic! I understand how the actual calculation can be done using the method of discs, but it really bugs me to not know why the above is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In a triangle, each horizontal line of length $l$ has weight proportional to $l$. But in a three-dimensional cone, each disk of radius $l$ has a weight proportional to $l^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Even though in the 2-D cutout, which is an isosceles triangle, we get that the center of mass is $\frac{1}{3}$ of the height, when we rotate the triangle around, parts further away from the axis of rotation, i.e. the base, will end up contributing a much greater area. Hence, we can expect that the center of mass is lower.

---

A similar result holds on the 2-D version of your example, if you were to look at the center of mass of a quadrant circle. The center of mass of a line will be the midpoint, but as you rotate it about the center, you clearly see that the circumference contributes a much greater mass. Hence, the center of mass of a quadrant is not on the midpoint of the center line.